# error cannot simplicity convert string to system.collection.generic.ienumerable on view

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

**Problem**

> Error: Cannot simplicity convert string to
>   System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable on view
>   of index

**Details**

I need to display every department and his employees following to it in tree view using jtree I downloaded from nuget in MVC 5 Visual Studio 2015 as department parent and children employee:

Sales (parent)
michel (children)
divid (children)

My database data as following:

```
SELECT dbo.Departments.DepartmentName, dbo.Employee.EmployeeName, dbo.Employee.DepartmentID
FROM dbo.Employee 
INNER JOIN dbo.Departments 
ON dbo.Employee.DepartmentID = dbo.Departments.DepartmentID
```

And treeviewhelper class has following function for children:

```
 public TreeView<T> Children(Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
 {
            //  if (selector == null) //throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");  
            _childrenProperty = selector;
            return this;
 }
```

My employee controller as following:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
        // GET: Employee
        HRSystem hr = new HRSystem();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Employee> catgory1 = hr.Employees.Where(x => !x.DepartmentID.HasValue).ToList();
            return View(catgory1);
        }
}
```

My error show on view of index as following:

```
@model IEnumerable<EmployeeSystem.Employee>
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using EmployeeSystem.Models;

<h2>TreeView</h2>
<link href="~/Content/jsTree/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-body">
    <div id="jstree">
        @(Html.TreeView(Model)
                              .EmptyContent("root")
                              .Children(m=>m.EmployeeName)
                              .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "tree" })
                          .ChildrenHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "subItem" })
                              .ItemText(m => m.EmployeeName)
                              .ItemTemplate(
        @<text>
            <a href="@item.EmployeeName" desc="@item.EmployeeName">@item.EmployeeName</a>
        </text>)
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

Employee model

```
public partial class Employee
{

        [Key]
        public int EmployeeNo { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

}
```

Department model

```
 public partial class Department
 {

        public Department()
        {
            Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Error displayed on line `Children(m=>m.EmployeeName)` on view of index.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind exception is obvious: you're assigning `EmployeeName` string property to `Children` method of `TreeView` helper which expects [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Consider adding `ICollection<T>` property as noted in [this article](http://matthidinger.com/archive/2011/11/27/Writing-a-Fluent-ASP-NET-MVC-Recursive-TreeView-Helper/) inside `Employee` class like this:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeNo { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    // add this property
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeeChilds { get; set; }
}
```

Then, use that virtual property to `Children` method of `TreeView`:

```
@(Html.TreeView(Model)
      .EmptyContent("root")
      .Children(m => m.EmployeeChilds) // insert ICollection property here
      .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "tree" })
      .ChildrenHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "subItem" })
      .ItemText(m => m.EmployeeName)
      .ItemTemplate(
        @<text>
            <a href="@item.EmployeeName" desc="@item.EmployeeName">@item.EmployeeName</a>
        </text>)
)
```

You can see example implementation of MVC TreeView in this reference:

[Creating TreeView For MVC 5](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-treeview-to-mvc-razor-view/)